# transformScale in turf.js flips, mirrors, and moves resulting polygons

Tags: transform, scale, turfjs

Using the polygon points shown below, why does turf.js output the results that it does when applying transformScale? The new enlarged polygon is not only upside down and mirrored, but is also shifted far away from the original, when it should appear over top of it in the same orientation.

The attached image shows two polygons with this problem. The ones with solid lines are the originals, the ones with dashed lines are the result of transformScale.

The original array of lat/lng coordinates is put into a turf polygon and then scaled by these two lines of code:

```
var poly = turf.polygon([polyPoints]);
var bufferPts = turf.transformScale(poly, 1.25).geometry.coordinates[0];
```

[image: polygon coordinates before and after applying transformScale]

[image: map showing polygons before and after applying transformScale]

Thanks for any assistance in understanding the problem as well as correcting it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u should try define option parameter in turf function, point of scale (center, centroid and so on).

See docs turf.js for turf.transformScale.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).